# C# Include DLL in a Library DLL

Tags: c#, dll

I have the following problem:

I'm making a library with few non-windows dependecies.
I would like to make the dll in order to have all the dependecies included without need to have also the other dll together with it.
The idea is to have only the new dll with the project that it'll use it instead of having also all the dependecies that this new dll is using.

I've read about inlcluding them as resource but it appears to not work as expected, using this code (I'm calling it in a static constructor of the class that need that dependecies, all the dependecies are in a subfolder lib of the library project):

```
    internal static void Include()
    {
        if (!included)
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, args) =>
            {
                String resourceName = "namespaceOfTheLibrary" + ".lib." + new AssemblyName(args.Name).Name + ".dll";

                using (var stream = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
                {
                    Byte[] assemblyData = new Byte[stream.Length];

                    stream.Read(assemblyData, 0, assemblyData.Length);

                    return Assembly.Load(assemblyData);
                }
            };

        included = true;
    }
```

This would be very helpfull in order to keep the code updated in many projects without forget any dependecies.

Hope something it's possible.

Thanks